# jQuery fadeTo not working in firefox/chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I'm trying to do a simple example using jQuerys fadeTo method.  It works as expected in IE8, but doesn't fade out Chrome/Firefox 3.6.  Niether the fadeTo call or the one in the button click work in chrome/ff.  Any ideas?

Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("img, div").fadeTo("slow", .5);

        $("input").click(function () {
            $("img, div").fadeTo("slow", .1);
        });
    });
```

The html contains a simple img and div tag. I'm trying to figure out how to get the html to display on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works just fine for me in Chrome (4.0.249.89 (38071)) and Firefox (3.5.8). My guess is that your problem is elsewhere. Be sure that you're not loading a cached version in the other browsers. This is the only cause I can immediately think of that would cause such an issue.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ijovu/edit

Comment: Seemed I was using a buggy version of jQuery.  I was actually referencing the vsdoc version of 1.4.1.  When I changed it to the minned version, it worked fine.

Comment: That was definitely my problem. VSDOC version shouldn't be used outside of VS. Odd, how it's buggy.

Comment: This is a bug on jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js. If you change it to other version your problem will be solved.