# FadeIn not working for FireFox/Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the simple `fadeIn` function below. It works perfectly in Chrome, but for some reason does not work in FireFox or Internet Explorer.

How can I fix this, so it works for all browsers?

```
function fadeinGray(){
   $('.dark-gray').fadeTo(1600, 1);
}

.dark-gray {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #202020;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331552/jquery-fadeto-not-working-in-firefox-chrome

Comment: @u_mulder I don't think I am using a buggy version of jQuery. I am using 1.11.3

Comment: This happens on multiple pages, not just one area. Everything works great in Chome.

Comment: Just tried it in Firefox 44.0.2 and IE11, no problem. Could you create a demo?

Comment: where did you call the function? fadeinGray()

Comment: I'm calling it in the file it is in, right before the closing body tag. Feel free to look at it live. It is the last thing on this page: http://optimumwebdesigns.com/test_index

Comment: @Becky check my answer below, you just need to lesser down the fading value, < 1

Comment: Try moving the definition of the fadeinGray function higher, above the function that calls it. If you put a debugger in the method, you'll see it's not even being called.

Comment: If you use Firebug or the Firefox JS console and just invoke `$('.dark-gray').fadeTo(1600, 1);`, it works just fine. So it's not a Firefox issue. Manual invocation in IE11 works fine, too.

Comment: @Nate How would I put a debugger in it?

Comment: In the Javascript, simply put "debugger;" on a new line. Then make sure to open your Developer Console (should just have to press F12), enable debugging in older versions of IE, and refresh the page. Whenever the Javascript execution comes to that statement, everything will pause and allow you to inspect the code at that point, and the state of all the variables as well.

Comment: You can also set a Javascript breakpoint.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger

Comment: So, basically it kills the code after that to allow the developer to zone in on the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it, you need to change the line `var pTop = $("body").scrollTop();` to `var pTop = $(document).scrollTop();`

you `pTop` var always returns 0 in some browsers, because of which it wasn't entering into the condition to execute your function `fadeinGray`

Comment: Why would it need to be less than 1? I want it to be full opacity. Why would this work perfectly in Chrome the way it is if that was the case?

Comment: @Becky, very importantly, fade represents itself to add up some dullness in some color, so if you wanna add dullness you need to make less than 1, in order to get it faded. else it won't be fading. and even you didn't add the function call in your question to make it clear to everyone. this wasn't the problem of function, this was the problem of function call..

Comment: What do you mean ^^^^^. This worked for me, though! Thanks. BTW, in firefox, there is not whitespace under the gray div, but in Chrome there is? I see it has to do with my nav menu, but do not see what.

Comment: The code `if( pTop > oTop )` is being executed just fine, @ameenulla0007. Downvoted because your first answer was also incorrect, then you edited it and suggested another provably incorrect answer.

Comment: no issues buddy @Nate, if you try giving an alert or console for pTop, you always get 0 as a return (in Firefox Particularly), because of which it didn't execute the fading function.

Comment: @nate His solution did help and makes this fade now, so I believe his solution is correct.

Comment: @Becky Ok, kudos. I'll withdraw my downvote when SO allows.

Comment: Hey no issues buddy @Nate, I'm not here to gain reputation. It is fun solving issues, thanks all.. :)

Comment: @ameenulla0007 Thanks!! Do you have any idea about the whitespace under the `dark-gray` div in chrome?